# gruntjs - where to install tasks?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Working on a [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) 'Hello World' project, and there doesn't seem to be an optimal place to install a grunt task.  Say, for instance, that I want to start compiling coffeescript, I would need the 'grunt-coffee' task installed.

### Option 1: Install it right into my src tree

This seems to be [the way grunt would like you to do it](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/api.md#gruntloadnpmtasks), and it works.

```
cd $MY_PROJECT_HOME
npm install grunt-coffee
grunt coffee
```

However, this adds 7.2mg to my project tree.  I don't want to put it in my src control, but if I remove it, grunt will not build my project.  I could .gitignore it, but then others that download the repository cannot build without doing the same installations.  This also gets a bit messy for CI servers.

### Option 2: Install it globally

```
cd $MY_PROJECT_HOME
npm install -g grunt-coffee
grunt coffee
```

Grunt can't find my plugins if I install them this way:

```
Local Npm module "grunt-coffee" not found. Is it installed?
```

It's not clear to me why this wouldn't be supported.

### Option 3: Install them somewhere else?

Grunt has an api method called [loadTasks](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/api.md#gruntloadtasks), which loads tasks locally.  I tried pulling down the npms and moving them myself into a custom directory that I referenced here, with no luck.  EG

```
grunt.loadTasks('$SHARED_TASKS_FOR_ALL_MY_GRUNT_PROJECTS/node_modules/grunt-coffee')
```

and then:

```
cd $SHARED_TASKS_FOR_ALL_MY_GRUNT_PROJECTS
npm install grunt-coffee
cd $MY_PROJECT_HOME
grunt coffee

Task "coffee" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

### Option 4: Grunt, in its loadNpmTasks call, pulls down dependencies for me in a .grunt directory somewhere

That'd be nice... :)

---

### EDIT

Sindre below is correct.  Option 1 is the way to go, but there is one part missing - the package.json file.  So:

- Add a package.json file and put all of your grunt project's [dependencies in there](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies).
- Ensure that `node_modules` is `.gitignore`-ed.
- In your README, give some instructions to run `npm install` (note, no arguments) upon a clone or if they add dependencies to the build file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First option is the correct way. You don't commit the node_modules folder, but instead just instruct users to do `npm install` which fetches all the required dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Sindre, that's the answer.  I expanded a bit upon it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use option 3, the correct syntax would be this:

```
grunt.loadTasks('$SHARED_TASKS_FOR_ALL_MY_GRUNT_PROJECTS/node_modules/grunt-coffee/tasks')
```

We have to use this somehow for our build process that runs on a computer isolated from "the outside world" and cannot pull in dependencies at build time...